# Prefix properties of multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers

Tags: spring, properties

I want to use Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to read two property files. I can load each of them by using one of the following tags:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="class path:com/myapp/internal.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="file://${settings.location}/external.properties"/>
```

I am not allowed to change the keys in those two files. Both files may contain entries with the same key.

I need to inject the value of a specific file.

```
//Pseudocode of injecting a property of a specific file
@Value("${internal.properties:my.key}")
String internalValue;

@Value("${external.properties:my.key}")
String externalValue;
```

So how to specify the file, and not only the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to translate it to xml if needed:

```
public class InternalPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer{

public UploaderPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {

    setLocations(new ClassPathResource[]{
      new ClassPathResource("com/myapp/internal.properties"),
    });

    setPlaceholderPrefix("$internal{");
    setPlaceholderSuffix("}");

}
```

and register it in spring ( or use @Component in above class ):

```
@Bean
public InternalPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new InternalPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

this way you should be able to inject properties with this rather ugly syntax:

```
@Value("$internal{your.key}")
private String value;
```

If it works, then just add 2nd bean for external :)

Comment: Looks good, but how to set the placeholder prefix in xml? There's no such attribute defined in the xsd.

Comment: you probably need to set up new/different bean, note that  this is PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, not just PropertyPlaceholder.I havent used xml for like 2 years so you need to dig in :)